# Create a new file in Android emulator path /data/

Tags: android

I want to create a file in emulator android storage path /data/...

but it seems I can't create a new file by programs,

I should upload an empty file to /data/... and then write the file,

Can anyone help here?

openFileOutput("file.txt", MODE_PRIVATE) seems can create a new file in /data/data/Package/files/...

but it can't create in path /data/...

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write directly to /data/ folder unless you have a rooted device. If you want to use /data/ directory then I would suggest using

```
/data/local/tmp/
```

Comment: This directory is only available on particular Android versions

Comment: Good to know, however, sadly, it is another nail in Android's fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

This code can write a new file to the `/data/data/Package/files/` folder. This may be the same with your code:

```
public void setparameter(int ilevel){
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
  buffer[0] = (byte)ilevel;
  OutputStream output = null;
  try{
   output = openFileOutput("option.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
   output.write(buffer);
   output.flush();
   output.close();
  }catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question asked